# How to load the first page based upon the FormsAuthentication.setCookie...?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the code `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Name, model.RememberMe);`

My question is as follows: How can I load the first page without going through the logOn form when `null != @Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` when loading the application?

What is the piece of code and where should I place it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by the *first page*? Can't you simply redirect to it:

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
```

after setting the authentication cookie with `SetAuthCookie`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you set a persistent authentication cookie, how do you prevent the user from going to the login screen first?  If so, I would think that this would only be an issue if your default page IS your login page, which generally isn't what most sites do.  Most sites have a default page be whatever they want the user to first see when they go to their site.  If that page requires authentication, then you will redirect them to your login page.  After they log in, you redirect them to wherever they were trying to go in the first place (if a user is redirected to a login page by ASP.NET security settings, then there is a ReturnUrl query string value that is the relative URL of where they were trying to go to first.

Also, if you are thinking of forcing them to the same page after they log in every time, I generally recommend not doing that, as it makes bookmarks completely useless on your site.